# How to split IP range to route usable form

Tags: c#, ip

I have a IP data file that contain a series of IP range data. I want to split it to route usable form.
 **Use C# code to parse it.**

**Example:**

**input**
1.0.1.0 ~ 1.0.11.255

**output**

1.0.1.0\255.255.255.0

1.0.2.0\255.255.254.0

1.0.4.0\255.255.252.0

1.0.10.0\255.255.254.0

---

Updated  here is my code

```
class Program
{
    const string datafile = @"....txt";

    static List<Pair> list = new List<Pair>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datafile))
        {
            int id = 0;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    IPAddress f = IPAddress.None;
                    IPAddress e = IPAddress.None;
                    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.None;
                    IPAddress mask = IPAddress.None;

                    string[] ss = reader.ReadLine().Split('\t');
                    f = IPAddress.Parse(ss[0]);
                    e = IPAddress.Parse(ss[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", f, e);

                    ip = f;

                    byte[] fb = f.GetAddressBytes();
                    byte[] eb = e.GetAddressBytes();
                    byte[] mb = new byte[fb.Length];

                    uint fi = 0, ei = 0, x, step = 1;
                    fi = ToUInt(fb);
                    ei = ToUInt(eb);
                    x = fi ^ ei;
                    while ((x & 1) == 1)
                    {
                        x >>= 1;
                        step <<= 1;
                    }
                    for (uint i = fi; i < ei; i += step)
                    {
                        Pair pair = new Pair();
                        pair.IP = new IPAddress(ToBytes(i));
                        pair.Mask = new IPAddress(ToBytes(~(step - 1)));
                        Insert(pair);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }

    static uint ToUInt(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Contract.Requires(bytes.Length == 4);
        uint u = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            u <<= 8;
            u |= bytes[i];
        }
        return u;
    }

    static byte[] ToBytes(uint u)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)(u & 0xff);
            u >>= 8;
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    static void Insert(Pair pair)
    {
        uint i = ToUInt(pair.IP.GetAddressBytes());
        uint m = ToUInt(pair.Mask.GetAddressBytes());
        uint x = m;
        uint d = 1;
        while ((x & 1) == 0)
        {
            d <<= 1;
            x >>= 1;
        }
        Pair pairPair = new Pair();
        pairPair.IP = new IPAddress(ToBytes(i ^ d));
        pairPair.Mask = pair.Mask;

        if (list.Contains(pairPair))
        {
            list.Remove(pairPair);
            Pair newPair = new Pair();
            newPair.Mask = new IPAddress(ToBytes(m << 1));
            newPair.IP = new IPAddress(ToBytes(i & ~d));
            Insert(newPair);
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(pair);
        }
    }
}

class Pair
{
    public IPAddress IP { get; set; }
    public IPAddress Mask { get; set; }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Pair pair = obj as Pair;
        if (pair == null) return false;
        return pair.Mask.ToString() == this.Mask.ToString() && pair.IP.ToString() == this.IP.ToString();
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", IP, Mask);
    }
}
```

Comment: @svick of course i tried, but i have no ideal do it.

Comment: `Use C# code to parse it` So you want us to write your code for you?

Comment: @L.B I am sorry, I have tried but I cannot write a fast algorithm to parse it. so I need a description of this algorithm but have code is best.

Comment: So you were able to write an algorithm that is too slow for your needs?

Comment: I think it is a good idea to post your code.

Comment: So, you have some code. What's wrong with it?